# Why Canvas.SetTop animation doesn't work properly?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, animation

I have this xaml:

```
    <Canvas Width="75" Height="75">
        <Button x:Name="button" Background="Olive" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Width="75" Height="75" Click="button_Click"/>
    </Canvas>
```

And this code behind:

```
    Private Sub button_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        Canvas.SetTop(sender, -75)

        Dim sb1 As New Storyboard
        Dim da1 As New DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        da1.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(da1, CType(sender, Button).Name)
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da1, New PropertyPath(Canvas.TopProperty))

        Dim t1 As Double = Canvas.GetTop(sender)
        da1.KeyFrames.Add(New SplineDoubleKeyFrame(t1 + 75, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)))
        sb1.Children.Add(da1)

        BeginStoryboard(sb1)        
    End Sub
```

When I click the button the first time, it properly goes up by 75 and animates back to 0, but when I click the button again, it just animates down by 75. Why is it skipping the Canvas.SetTop line and goes straight to the animating part? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code (it is in C#) before Canvas.SetTop

```
(sender as UIElement).BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, null);
```

This will avoid that any animation overrides the value Canvas.TopProperty

This link will help you

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/08/21/removing-the-value-applied-by-an-animation/